# Windows Azure linux domain

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain, windows, azure

I've set up a Virtual Machine and I need to connect my domain .site.com to Windows Azure, I tried to do it with an A record using the provided IP, but the VIP address is not static, and after restarting my server the IP was changed and the site using my domain doesn't work.
If I use CNAME - I can't connect root domain .site.com. Now my site is working for www but without www it doesn't work.

How can I setup a static VIP or connect root domain in Linux Windows Azure server? Or maybe I can use some redirect or something else? I can't find a manual for this problem.

Comment: You want to use the [microsoft guide for configuring domains on azure.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/) It's a bit convoluted (especially if you're used to managing your own servers / DNS) but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Reserve the IP address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690120.aspx) so that it won't change across reboots. It won't change even if you delete the VM and create it again (in the same xxx.cloudapp.net domain - here called cloud service)

For more check out also the [Configuring custom Domain for Azure cloud service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/).

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use [Instance Public IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/), can be use this feature in new Azure portal to create a vm instance with "Resource Manager" mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine isn't going to be running constantly, and you don't want to be charged for a static IP address, and are running the machine as an Azure Resource Management (v2) VM, you can create a cname pointing to name.location.cloudapp.azure.com